# Tightening Stud Without Bolt Head

Tags: maintenance, repair

What would be the best way to tighten a stud without a bolt head? It essentially looks like this. [image]

I need to tighten it to a specific torque(4 of these have nuts tightened on them to hold the tire of my bike to the right fork). I have no idea how I would do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You take 2 nuts and put them on the same set of threads.  Then lock them against each other by loosening the lower nut and tightening the upper nut.  Then use the upper nut with your torque wrench to install the stud.